# 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str' when accessing nested lists

Tags: python, list, types

I am trying to build a Tkinter program that displays vertically stacked text fields with labels. Next to each of these fields there are two other text fields with labels. I want to be able to add vertically and horizontally add more fields with labels.

In a `Data` class I have store a list `assets` that is build like this:

```
assets = [[[vertical_label, vertical_input],[[horizontal_label_1, horizontal_input_1],[horizontal_label_2, horizontal_input_2]]]]
```

so that

- `assets[i]` is an asset
- `assets[i][0]` is the vertical part of which `[0]` is the label and `[1]` is the input
- `asserts[i][1]` is the horizontal part of which `[j][0]` is the label of the `jth` horizontal item

In my code i have called each horizontal item `ticker`.

Now, I need to actually add the asset to the window for which I coded a function `Data.update()`

```
def update():
    asset_index = 0
    asset = Data.assets[0]
    asset[0][0].grid(row=asset_index, column=0)
    asset[0][1].grid(row=asset_index, column=1)

    ticker_index = 2

    ticker = asset[1][0]
    ticker[0][0].grid(row=asset_index, column=ticker_index)
    ticker[0][1].grid(row=asset_index, column=ticker_index + 1)

    ticker[1][0].grid(row=asset_index + 1, column=ticker_index)
    ticker[1][1].grid(row=asset_index + 1, column=ticker_index + 1)
```

But for the line `ticker[0][0].grid(row=asset_index, column=ticker_index)` it throws the error.

How is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you go one level too deep with your subscripts:

`ticker = asset[1][0]`
gives you
`ticker = [horizontal_label_1, horizontal_input_1]`
so I think with ticker[0][0] you get the first letter of your horizontal label not the label itself.

I guess what you want is
`ticker = asset[1]` before the line that throws the error and then it should be fine.

Comment: That helped. Why did it throw the `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not 'int') to str` error though?

Comment: good question. print(asset[1][0][0][0]) maybe you get an answer that way by seeing what you tried to put into .grid(). Don't know where the concatenation comes in though...